# Creating a left join condition using where clause in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I want to create a condition in where clause, that can imitate left join. For example:

```
From Table1, Table2 Where table1.ID *= table2.ID
```

needs to be written as

```
From Table1, Table2
Where Table1.ID = Table2.ID AND (some condition to get the rows from table1 where match does not exist)
```

I want to do this, because the existing query builder function calls like dozen functions to create the final query, and same function is called from 100+ pages. So, updating FROM clause to use `Left Join` will break the whole flow, and cause a whole lot of headache. I would rather just update the WHERE clause itself.

Comment: I am not aware that MySQL has any syntax for supporting a `left join` in the `where` clause.  If it did, I certainly would not advocate using it.

Comment: I don't want it to support `left join` clause as is. I can easily get results of inner join though. If somehow I can get the results of those rows where match doesn't exist, I can combine these two result sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, a `where` clause cannot increase the number of rows in the result set.  So, you cannot formally reproduce a `left join` in the `where` clause.

That said, it is possible that this would do what you want:

```
From Table1, Table2
Where (Table1.ID = Table2.ID or
       not exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.id = table1.id) 
      )
```

This doesn't quite formally replicate the `left join`.  For instance, if `Table2` is empty, then the `from` clause returns no rows at all, so nothing is returned.  However, it might work for your case.

Comment: Nice. This will do, I guess. Let me test it tomorrow and get back to you. BTW, if there is no row in table2 where `t2.id = table1.id`, then, not exists condition will simply return true, right?

Comment: Thanks to Prasanth's link, I can test queries on my phone too. Tested your suggested query, works great.

Comment: @jitendragarg . . . The logic in the `where` clause makes sense when `table2` is empty.  The problem is that the `cross join` in the `from` clause will return no rows, so there are no rows to operate on.

Comment: This is weird. Yesterday, I tried, it worked fine. Now, the same query returns completely different result set. :/

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`Name` varchar(5), `Age` int)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`Name`, `Age`)
VALUES
    ('PVJ', 10),
    ('EPF', 12),
    ('CISCO', 13)
;

CREATE TABLE Table2
    (`Name` varchar(3), `Age` int)
;

INSERT INTO Table2
    (`Name`, `Age`)
VALUES
    ('PVJ', 10),
    ('EPF', 12),
    ('DVF', 13)

select Table1.Name,(select Table2.Age from Table2 where Table1.Name=Table2.Name)  Age from table1
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7dbd4/17

Comment: Nice. I didn't know about sqlfiddle. That's a great place. Although, as for the query itself, I can't update anything else apart from where clause. Changing anything else will mean changing some 2-3 common function's definition; aka breaking the whole damn code. (I know, it is the stupidest design, but what do you expect from dinosaurs who used *= in the first place).

Answer (score 0):

From my current understanding of relational-algebra, this is not possible.
The left outer join only joins where a counterpart int the right table exists.

You could use two Queries, one being the join, and one being a select with "where not_exists(select 1 from table2 where table2.id=table1.id)"
You then union those two sets, this will result in your outer join.

Comment: Hmm. Let me try that. For now, I was using `where (table1.id = table2.id OR table2.id IS NULL)`. Alternatively, can I do a full outer join, using where clauses? If that works, I can easily remove the extra rows where table1.id is null.

Comment: hi.
if you select from table1,table2 internally, the database produces a cartesian product from the rows of each table. This means each row of table1 will be "joined" with each row of table2.
The where clause now restricts it to the ones that actually map.

With your approach, you will get duplicate rows of table1.
You could now try solving this by using distinct, but soon or late you are running into performance problems.

Comment: No, where clauses cannot fully replicate the joins.

Comment: Performance is fine. We just upgraded our servers to use four times as much CPU power and RAM. Plus this application is supposed to last for just 2-3 years. So, all of this is just to tide things over.